# I Have 10,000 record in my table when bind it with GridView Only 266 record back?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I Have **10,000** record in my table on SqlServer DB  when I bind it using SqlDataAdapter with GridView on Asp.net page with **3** textbox and button to filter the data I only get **266** record instead of 10,000 record when I use **(%)** to retrieve all my data Any help to solve the problem and my query is like that:

```
SELECT
COALESCE (IQCRM_NUM, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS ASIQCRM_NUM
 , COALESCE (Full_name, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS ASFull_name,
 COALESCE (Mother_Name, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Mother_Name, 
 COALESCE (Date_of_Birth, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Date_of_Birth,
 COALESCE (Province_of_birth, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Province_of_birth,
 COALESCE (Job, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Job 
 FROM [Criminal Main Table] 
 WHERE 
 (Full_name LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%' OR @Full_name IS NULL) 
 AND (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%' OR @Mother_Name IS NULL) 
 AND (Date_of_Birth LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%' OR @Date_of_Birth IS 
 NULL)
```

AND GridView Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84"
                    BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2"
                    DataKeyNames="ASIQCRM_NUM" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%" PageSize="100">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ASIQCRM_NUM" HeaderText="IQCRM_NUM" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ASIQCRM_NUM" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ASFull_name" HeaderText="Full_name" 
                            SortExpression="ASFull_name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mother_Name" HeaderText="Mother_Name" 
                            SortExpression="Mother_Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date_of_Birth" HeaderText="Date_of_Birth" 
                            SortExpression="Date_of_Birth" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Province_of_birth" HeaderText="Province_of_birth" 
                            SortExpression="Province_of_birth" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Job" HeaderText="Job" SortExpression="Job" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

SQlDataAdapter Code is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CriminalDBBefore2003ConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT COALESCE (IQCRM_NUM, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS ASIQCRM_NUM, COALESCE (Full_name, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS ASFull_name, COALESCE (Mother_Name, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Mother_Name, COALESCE (Date_of_Birth, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Date_of_Birth, COALESCE (Province_of_birth, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Province_of_birth, COALESCE (Job, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS Job FROM [Criminal Main Table] WHERE (Full_name LIKE N'%' + @Full_name + N'%' OR @Full_name IS NULL) AND (Mother_Name LIKE N'%' + @Mother_Name + N'%' OR @Mother_Name IS NULL) AND (Date_of_Birth LIKE N'%' + @Date_of_Birth + N'%' OR @Date_of_Birth IS NULL)"
                    OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" 
                    OnSelected="SqlDataSource1_Selected">
                     <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Full_name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"
                            ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false"   />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="Mother_Name" PropertyName="Text"
                            Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox3" Name="Date_of_Birth" PropertyName="Text"
                            ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**What is Wrong with it?**

Comment: you're missing your .net code, why are you expecting all 10000 records rather than the 266 you're getting.  Are you saying if you run your select query you get 10,000 in SSMS, but if you run that (seemingly the same?) query in your data adapter you only get 266?

Comment: @Kritner when I run the query on my query builder in data adapter I get 10,000 record but when I run it from my asp.net page I get only 266 record any help,

Comment: Try running profiler to see what the actual query is being passed to your sql server.

Comment: You are also missing the leading N in your coalesce statements which may be causing you some issues.

Comment: @SeanLange where to but N in the statement ?? lets say that example  COALESCE (IQCRM_NUM, 'لاتوجد بيانات') AS ASIQCRM_NUM

Comment: Your string literal will be interpreted as a varchar and unless IQCRM_NUM is nvarchar it will return it as varchar. And if the column is nvarchar then it will be an implicit conversion. This would be better. COALESCE (IQCRM_NUM, N'لاتوجد بيانات')

Comment: @SeanLange Ok I will do it and return the result , but tell me what u mean by profiler I dont under stand ??

Comment: SQL Server Profiler. It is an application installed with sql server. Open a query in SSMS and then click Tools -> Sql Server Profiler. You can find articles on the internet that explain how to use the filtering and such. To be honest you need to use this so you can determine the actual query being executed.

Comment: I have try The N But it's keep give me the same result I will use Profiler and give u the result

Comment: The WHERE condition doesn't include the case where the column value is NULL, maybe change `OR @Full_name IS NULL` to `OR Full_name IS NULL` (and the same for the other 2 columns in the WHERE clause)